# Verizon CDN rules engine no-cache rules

Tags: azure, cdn, verizon

I would like to know how to setup rules to add no-cache policies to different starting-paths of a domain as a relative link.

For example domain.com/ should have default cache.
domain.com/umbraco should have bypass cache
domain.com/umbraco/nested/yes should have bypass cache
domain.com/xxx/ should have bypass cache

and so on.

First rule setting I choose is URL, second URL Path literal, however what I am uncertain of is the result setting and value according to the image below...

[image]

I would appreciate if someone that uses Verizon could show an example of some rulesets that determine the basepath of the relative url with or without regex.